# How to fix: cannot import name 'logsumexp'

Tags: ubuntu, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels, sklearn-pandas

I am working on Jupyter notebook. My code was working fine but then I installed sklearn for some other project and now my current code stopped working. It suddenly started showing "cannot import name 'logsumexp'" error.

I have tried upgrading sklearn, scikit-learn and statsmodels. There were some suggestions that rolling back to scikit 0.18.02 model would  help but that didn't work either. I think this link explains the reason of error ' https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.logsumexp.html ' but I still don't know how to fix it.

These are my current versions

scikit-learn          0.21.2
scipy                 1.3.0
sklearn               0.0
statsmodels           0.9.0

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-de89bb760177> in <module>
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 from matplotlib import cm
----> 5 from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt
      6 import statsmodels.api as sm

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/api.py in <module>
     23 from .statespace.varmax import VARMAX
     24 from .statespace.dynamic_factor import DynamicFactor
---> 25 from .regime_switching.markov_regression import MarkovRegression
     26 from .regime_switching.markov_autoregression import MarkovAutoregression
     27 from .holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/regime_switching/markov_regression.py in <module>
     11 import statsmodels.base.wrapper as wrap
     12 
---> 13 from statsmodels.tsa.regime_switching import markov_switching
     14 
     15 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/regime_switching/markov_switching.py in <module>
     13 from statsmodels.compat.collections import OrderedDict
     14 
---> 15 from scipy.misc import logsumexp
     16 from statsmodels.base.data import PandasData
     17 import statsmodels.tsa.base.tsa_model as tsbase

ImportError: cannot import name 'logsumexp'
```

Comment: try to change `from scipy.misc import logsumexp` to `from scipy.special import logsumexp`

Answer (score 2):

I am quoting the answer from a [Github issue](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5759):

`statsmodels 0.9` is not compatible with `SciPy 1.3.0`. The current master branch is compatible and the next release will be compatible. The options are to downgrade SciPy, install in a `virtual- or conda-env` with `SciPy 1.2`, or to install from master branch using the code provided below

`pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels`

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the packages:

This does not happen on statsmodel 0.10.1

```
pip install -U scikit-learn scipy statsmodels
```

If you want a stable environment everytime, I suggest to use conda pinned versions rather than upgrading individual packages.